# What's the easiest way to create an empty shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

If you have a type that is quite long, in a `shared_ptr`, what's the easiest way to return the equivalent of a null pointer?  In C++03 I was doing the following, but I'm wondering whether C++11 has introduced any better alternatives?

```
std::shared_ptr<
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::map<std::string, std::string>>>
> getComplicatedType()
{
    // Do some checks, can't create type, so return an empty shared_ptr
    return std::shared_ptr<
        std::vector<std::pair<int, std::map<std::string, std::string>>>
    >();
}
```

I realise you could use `typedef` to create an alias for the type, but I'm looking for a nicer solution where the compiler can deduce the type automatically.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`return nullptr;`

Possibly a little more clear than `return {};`

Answer (score 7):

```
return {};
```

This value-initializes the return type, which in the case of a smart pointer initializes it to null.

Comment: For class types, that requires a non-explicit default ctor, though.